# Fix gold plating on pins has been to repair charging

Tags: charging, repair, gold

To begin, apologies in advance if this is the wrong place for this kind of question.

I have a Fitbit where the gold plating on the charging pins are fading causing inconsistent charging. Is there a way/has anyone had success repairing charging pins that have this kind of damage? Would I need to replace the gold, or could i just add normal solder?

Thanks

Comment: I would start by simply cleaning the pads with alcohol. Gold used on pads which see repeated scraping is usually hard gold, and does not actually wear away very easily. Make sure the pads aren't just dirty/grimy

Comment: Solder will only make things worse!  It will both interfere with the mechanical fit of the contacts and likely itself degrade when exposed to sweat.

Comment: @DerStrom8 thanks! i've cleaned with alcohol and early stages looking promising, will see over the next week to see if that was the issue